# how to render an array of objects in mustache tag

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

i have an array of objects as given below:

```
 var games_string = new Array();
 games_string[0] = { display_name: "sanket" };
 games_string[1] = { display_name: "sky" };
```

I want to render this array of objects in mustache tag in html page.
I referred this site http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html and found this solution but its not working...

```
 <table>
 <tr>
 {{#games_string}}
     <td>
        <b>{{display_name}}</b>
    </td>
 {{/games_string}}
 </tr>
 <table>
```

Comment: --> it does not render the display names.
--> I am calling this template using mojito framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example from the [fine manual](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) lays out the basic usage:

```
var view = {
  title: "Joe",
  calc: function () {
    return 2 + 4;
  }
};

var output = Mustache.render("{{title}} spends {{calc}}", view);
```

If your template is in `tmpl` then you'd want to do something like this:

```
var data = {
    games_string: [
        { display_name: "sanket" },
        { display_name: "sky" }
    ]
};
var html = Mustache.render(tmpl, data);
```

You need to give `render` an object to associate names with values, otherwise Mustache will have no idea what `{{#games_string}}` is supposed to refer to in the template. Just creating a variable called `games_string` isn't enough, you have to tell Mustache what data should be associated with the `games_string` name inside the template.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/9y7ju/

Comment: Thanks.. For that keen observation. I had completely skipped that.